# Getting one error while implementing the matrix class

Tags: oop, c++17, operator-overloading

```
matrix matrix::operator+(matrix& B)
{
    matrix sum(int m_row, int m_col);
    int i, j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            sum(i, j) = matrix_v[i][j] + B(i, j); //no operator '='matches these operands sum is of type matrix and matrix_v is of vector<vector<double> >
        }
    }
}
```

expecting to be executed without errors.
matrix_v is as vector of vector of type double and matrix is class I am not sure do i need to overload the = operator as well?

Comment: There's some code missing that is used in this function. Nobody will be able to assess the error without complete knowledge. E.g.: what does the code look like that is called by `sum(i, j)` (resp. `B(i, j)`)?
Another hint: read the complete error message of the compiler carefully. You will find more information there.

Comment: "sum is of type matrix" False. In your example, `sum` is declared to be a function that takes two `int` parameters and returns `matrix`; which is probably not what you meant. `sum(i, j)` then calls this function and produces a `matrix`. The assignment then appears to assign a `double` to a `matrix`